# How to print just the final sum of odd and even integers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Built a program that allows the user to input a number, then calculates the sum of all the odd integers and all the even integers between 1 and the input. How do I only print the final sum of the odd and even integers rather than the sum between each addition? Thank you!

```
    #Allow user to enter a number

n = input("Enter a number: ")
n = int(n)
n >= 1
total = 0


#sum of even numbers
for n in range(1, n+1):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        total += n
    
        print("Sum of even numbers: ", total)

#sum of odd numbers
total2 = 0
for n in range(1, n+1):
    if n % 2 == 1:
        total2 += n
    
        print("Sum of odd numbers: ", total2)
```

Comment: Dedent the print statements to be after the loop, not in it.

Comment: It looks like you have indented the two print statements when you meant to have no indent.

Comment: As an aside, the statement `n >= 1` does not do anything. It is a Boolean expression that will be evaluated to True or False but the result will be unceremoniously tossed on the floor.

Comment: You don't need to repeatedly test each value. `range(0, n+1, 2)` and `range(1, n+1, 2)` will yield the even and odd integers, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned before, you need to modify your indentation. Your code should look like that:

```
n = input("Enter a number: ")
n = int(n)
total = 0
#sum of even numbers
for n in range(1, n+1):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        total += n  
print("Sum of even numbers: ", total)

#sum of odd numbers
total2 = 0
for n in range(1, n+1):
    if n % 2 == 1:
        total2 += n   
print("Sum of odd numbers: ", total2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making 2 different loops, you can do it in one single loop too. Like the one below:

```
num = input("Enter a number: ")
num = int(num)

even = [] # Appends all the even integers present in the user-accepted input
odd = [] # Appends all the odd integers present in the user-accepted input

for n in range(1, num+1):
  if n % 2 == 0:
    even.append(n)
  else:
    odd.append(n)

print("Sum of Even integers : ", sum(even))
print("Sum of Odd integers : ", sum(odd))
```